# Put image into Mapview Marker Callout

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm creating an App with a Mapview and custom Mapmarkers, which works fine. What I would like to do is to add an image into the callout when the user taps one of the markers.

![enter image description here][1]

I made the same thing for iOS, where it has been pretty straightforward:
[image]

The [mapview-balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) library has support for this, but it's only for Google Maps V1.
I would need to show a different image for each callout, which will be hosted on a web server, so I will also have to download that image asynchronously somehow before showing it. Is there any good solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom InfoWindowAdapter, see [the API guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#showhide_an_info_window%20%22the%20API%20guide) for details